# Возврат множества из условия (аналог CASE)

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь написать запрос в Oracle, который использует разные множества для `IN()` в условии. Общий вид запроса примерно такой:

```
-- что-то забирает
WHERE id IN
  (CASE 
    WHEN name LIKE '%max%'
    THEN (1, 2, 5)
    ELSE (SELECT id FROM anotherTable)
  END);
```

Понятно, что такой вариант не работает и выдаёт ошибку `ora-01427`. Судя по тому, что я прочитал в сети, `CASE` не может вернуть множество.

Что можно использовать, чтобы вернуть именно множество?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй это

```
where (
         NAME like '%max%'
         and ID in (1, 2, 5)
      )
   or (
         NAME not like '%max%'
         and ID in (select ID from anotherTable)
      )
```

Comment: Работает, но не лучший вариант. Чего-то похожего на `CASE` вообще нет? Если условий 3 и больше, прописывать все эти `OR` будет очень долго и тоскливо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать еще так:

```
where 
  1 = case
        when name like '%max%' and id in (1,2,5) then 1
        when name like '%min%' and id in (select id from anotherTable) then 1
      end
```